# Its there a way to connect some bones when the are in different armatures?

Tags: rigging, bones, constraints

I have a model which has some parts like the hair and the body separate, and I even have some different bones that are connected to each object separately. Now I need a way to connect them while the are still are rig to their current object, so the character's moves are more fluid.

Can anybody tell me what to do? Do I need a constraint?

If need Picture to see my problem then ask for them?

Comment: Use *Child_Of constraint*. Don't forget to click the *Set Inverse* button.